# Numeric value out of range subtracting dates in jOOQ

Tags: java, h2, jooq

I'm trying to compare dates in jOOQ (v3.5.0) using the H2 database (v1.4.185), but I get "Numeric value out of range" if the comparison is too large.

For example, with the following table

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    deadline TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and using the following example code (jOOQ's code generation step not shown)

```
DSLContext dsl = DSL.using(getDataSource(dbUrl), SQLDialect.H2);

ExampleRecord exampleRecord = dsl.newRecord(EXAMPLE);
exampleRecord.setDeadline(Timestamp.valueOf("2001-01-10 12:15:30"));
exampleRecord.store();

dsl.selectFrom(EXAMPLE)
        .where(EXAMPLE.DEADLINE.sub(
              DayToSecond.valueOf(Duration.ofDays(30).toMillis()))
        .le(currentTimestamp()))
        .fetch().forEach(record -> System.out.println(record.getDeadline()));
```

yields the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: 
SQL [select "EXAMPLE"."ID", "EXAMPLE"."DEADLINE" from "EXAMPLE" 
where dateadd('ms', cast(? as bigint), "EXAMPLE"."DEADLINE") 
    <= current_timestamp()]; 
Numeric value out of range: "-2592000000"; 
SQL statement:
        select "EXAMPLE"."ID", "EXAMPLE"."DEADLINE" from "EXAMPLE" 
where dateadd('ms', cast(? as bigint), "EXAMPLE"."DEADLINE") 
    <= current_timestamp() [22003-185]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a flaw in H2 to me. H2's [`DATEADD()` function expects the number of units added to be of type `int`](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html?highlight=DATEADD&search=dateadd#dateadd). That doesn't make sense when operating with milliseconds, of course. [I've reported it on the H2 user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/GcletZDXTss). Let's see what they say. If this cannot be corrected in H2, we'll work around it in jOOQ as we've done with Sybase and other databases.

#### Workarounds:

The [`Field.sub(Number)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#sub-org.jooq.Field-) method when used for date time arithmetics already subtracts days from a timestamp (like Oracle). So, you *could* write the same expression as:

```
EXAMPLE.DEADLINE.sub(30)
```

Another option would be to use [`DSL.timestampAdd()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#timestampAdd-org.jooq.Field-java.lang.Number-org.jooq.DatePart-) instead:

```
timestampAdd(EXAMPLE.DEADLINE, -30, DatePart.DAY);
```

A third option is to resort to using plain SQL:

```
public static Field<Timestamp> mySub(Field<Timestamp> field, Number days) {
    return DSL.field("dateadd('day', {0}, {1})", Timestamp.class, val(-days), field);
}
```

Comment: Using days instead worked perfectly. Thanks! (and thanks for creating jOOQ - I would never use any other DB access technology now!)

Comment: @artbristol: Thanks for the nice words. We'll keep it up for you

Comment: @artbristol: [Noel Grandin from H2 has accepted the issue and fixed it](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/h2-database/GcletZDXTss/cxl-IsPudC8J). This will work in the next H2 version, so we won't work around it in jOOQ

Answer (score 2):

The error doesn't make sense for me. The generated SQL (`bigint`) suggests that jOOQ is aware that the argument is a `long` and `-2592000000` is well within within the limits.

I'm wondering is the quotes are added by the error message or if `DayToSecond.toMillis()` maybe returns a `String` instead of `long`. Except that I'd expect a different error message then (plus a compile error).

Just to be on the safe side, try to reduce the complexity of the expression by replacing code with constants:

```
dsl.selectFrom(EXAMPLE)
    .where(EXAMPLE.DEADLINE.sub(-2592000000L))
    ...
```

just to see how that affects the error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You get the same error with a constant. `DayToSecond.toMillis()` returns `DayToSecond` which extends `Number`, but the problem is the same with a `double` or `long` input (though the generated SQL is different, e.g. `cast(? as double))`

Comment: :-/ Which version of H2 and jOOQ? Maybe set a breakpoint when the error message is created and go up the stack to see which part of the code complains.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have to dig into the code. I've updated the question with the version numbers. I'm basically waiting for @Lukas Eder to turn up and save the day :-)